# Do starting strength twice a week instead of three?

Tags: workout-routines, starting-strength

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Doing Starting Strength once a week](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6329/doing-starting-strength-once-a-week)

I was thinking to do Starting Strength twice a week instead of three, on Mondays and Thursdays, because Fridays I tend to be busy with work and on Sundays I tend to be hangover. I know it will be slower than doing three times a week, but it is better than nothing.

My question is, will it completely destroy the Starting Strength program to reduce it to two workouts a week?

Comment: Why not Saturday?

Comment: Pretty much everything in [this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/6329/1771) applies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No

You will just be gaining a little slower. Other then that I don't see why you wouldn't be adding weights.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible to grow stronger muscles by working out two times a week. Make sure you train **every muscle group once a week** (not more). Your *muscles need time to rest*. Keep your workouts *under 30 minutes*.

To make that happen do the following: 
Two different exercises each **only one set** per muscle group. 
Don't rest more than 1.5 minute between sets.
**Make them burn!** Go all out. You should be breathing heavily for 30 minutes after the workout.

Comment: This doesn't seem to consider the Starting Strength program as part of the question.

Comment: @Jasper A. you clearly know nothing of proper training.